# Is array loaded entirely if an element is read? (Am I basically flushing my cache?)

Tags: c++, arrays, cpu-cache

I have an enum `EFoo` and want to use it as a key pointing to `static const Foo`s (or `constexpr` rather, but that's not really the point). Either way, `Foo` is bascially a bunch of parameters used by a large number of `Owner`s which have a list of `EFoo`s they can use. Since the list of active `Owner`s is large, I can't save `Foo` on each owner, so I'm using an enum like a pointer but it's easier to use as it's named (and as a bonus, smaller).

I'm basically concerned would I be basically flushing cache on each use / read / conversion of key to object if the read is from an array.

So, in regards to cache usage and supposing 80/20* use of objects, can the objects be laid out:

- option 1: in an array without polluting cache with the rest of array elements when read from; or
- option 2: to prevent cache pollution, each object must be defined separately?
- if same, option 1 is better because it doesn't require maintaining nor jumping through an additional switch list.
- by 80/20 I mean Pareto defined 80% of usage by 20% of sources.

Storage:

```cpp
// FooData.inl
#include Foo.h

// option 1: stored as array
static const Foo Foos[256] {
  /* A */ {...},
  /* B */ {...},
}

// option 2: stored as separate
namespace Foos {
  static const A { ... };
  ...
}
```

Usage:

```cpp
// Keys.h
enum class EFoo : uint8 { A, B, ... }
// Foo.h
struct Foo { ... void operator= (EFoo Key); }

// Foo.cpp
#include Foo.h
#include FooData.inl
void Foo::operator= (EFoo Key) {
  // option 1: read from array
  *this = Foos[(uint8)Key];
  // option 2: read from separate
  switch (Key) {
    case EFoo::A: *this = Foos::A; ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Depends on the cache size, the array (matrix) size and the organization (dimensions) of the array.  Also depends on how many other variables are in use.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking about.  As far as CPU caching is concerned, it does not know anything about data structures - rather it caches continuous memory areas. However, there is a good chance `static constexpr Foo` objects do not even exist after program compilation (depending on Foo definition), and the question of caching becomes irrelevant.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Say size of Foo is 128 B (a single Foo fits in cache), and array size is 256, single dimension (all Foos in this example would take pretty much entire 4 MB cache). Does that narrow it down?

Comment: @SergeyA Ok, struct is an abstraction, but it still takes memory. Say its definition includes integers and strings for a total size of 128 B. What does "not existing" mean in terms of memory usage and speed of access?

Comment: It means exactly that. `static constexpr` objects (as long as their constructors are constexpr) can often be completely eliminated by compiler.

Comment: Rather than trying to statically analyze the code by hand, it may better to just implement these and see what the outcomes are like (both wall-clock performance and CPU counters tracking cache hits/misses are helpful here). It could also very well be that your switch ends up creating a jump table/code in i-cache, reducing concerns about d-cache contention.

Comment: @SergeyA You mean they would be inlined, aka turned to memory defined as instructions?

Comment: @nanofarad Fair enough. Was hoping for some quick estimate ("back of envelope"), but, true, only measuring would solve the question.

Comment: Tip: Just use `std::vector`. In the vast majority of cases it's the best performing tool for the job. These play nice with CPU "read-ahead" caching.

Comment: @n-smits:  You'll have to look up the processor's cache size on your target platform.  If your cache is 1024 and sizeof(Foo) is 128, then you'll be able to fit 8 of them into the cache (1024/128 = 8).  However, if you access anything else from memory, some of the Foo objects may not be in the cache anymore.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Sure, that's how cache works, ok. But what you're saying is, no, the entire array won't be loaded?

Comment: @n-smits Let's take another example.  Let's say that the cache is 4096 bytes.  However, the processor is stupid and has no idea how big your array is.  The processor only fetches 1024 bytes from your present address.  In this case, the processor has not loaded your entire array into the cache (because it doesn't know how big the array is).  Look at the assembly language generated by your compiler.  See if there are any assembly instructions that tell how many bytes to load into the cache.

Comment: @n-smits even better: The CPU doesn't care about your structs. If you read a field from a struct from an array, the CPU usually only reads the one field and a couple adjacent fields into cache. Not even the whole struct, much less a whole array. On modern processors, a cache line is ~64 bytes, so thats how much data is read into cache.

Comment: Thank you both! That makes perfect sense!

Comment: Also, please post as answer.